# Why promise.all axios post, return 400, 404 error?

Tags: react-native

What I'm trying to do is to send multiply Axios request in one function.
Both requests have the same params.
I tried different ways to implement this but they all do come in the same error `Request failed with status code 400, Request failed with status code 404`

signUp.js

```
const SignUp = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  let register = "https://api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/auth/register" 
  let sendVerification= "https://api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/auth/sendVerification-otp"
 
  const signUp = () => {
    
    const userParams = {
      phone: phoneNumber,
    };
    
    Promise.all([
      axios.post(register, userParams),
      axios.post(sendVerification, userParams)
    ])
    .then(response => {
      const register1 = response[0].data
      const sendVerification1 = response[1].data
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message)
    })
}
return(
   <View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.ButtonSignUp} onPress={signUp}>
        <Text style={styles.ButtonText}>SIGN UP</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
);
}
export default SignUp;
```

Comment: What do you exactly retrieve in `response` and in `err`?

Comment: In response I retrieve success: true, for both of the responses, and the response message. The register api, registers the user in the database, and the second api, send a text msg to the user that has been registered.

Comment: Hmmm… Where exactly do you get your errors `Request failed with status code 400` and `Request failed with status code 404`?

Comment: 404 is for the second api, which checks if the phone number exists in the database,if it doesn't exist, shows 404 error

Comment: OK, but what are you expecting from axios or from your code? I understand that you retrieve 404 errors but why is it a problem? Can you explicit what is your problem with axios returning 404 and 400 errors and what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
let register = "https://api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/auth/register" 
let sendVerification= "https://api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/auth/sendVerification-otp"

const registerApi = axios.post(register , userParams );
const verificationApi = axios.post(sendVerification, userParams );

if (Promise && !Promise.allSettled) {
  Promise.allSettled = PromiseHelperAllSettled;
}

const [register1 ,sendVerification1 ] = await Promise.allSettled([registerApi, verificationApi]);
```